# Why i can't get the value of NSArray? It's always return nil value.Swift 4.3

Tags: swift, nsarray

I want to get the value of `NSArray`, but it always gives me `nil` value, Anyone knows how to solve it?

it is created by `swift 4.2`

```swift
KCNetWorkTool.tool.getRecordListWith(UserID: userID, Date: dateLabel.text!) { (result) in

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if let dict = result.data as NSDictionary? {
// the value of this below line, i cann't get . array always return nil
                if let array = (dict["list"] as? NSMutableArray) {
                    let countArray = array.count
                    for index in 0..<countArray {
                        if let dictNew = array[index] as? NSDictionary {
                            let row = EnvelopeModel(dictionary: dictNew)
                            self.recordModel.append(row)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            self.recordTable.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is Swift. Do not use `NSDictionary` and `NSArray`. Use a Swift dictionary and array.

Comment: But it doesn't work for me. still return nil

Comment: No one can help without any information. Do some debugging. What keys are actually in `dict`? Is there actually a value for `"list"`? Is that value actually an array?

Comment: this is the value of dict["list"],and the list is an array                         ▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : [
  {
    "billAmount" : 9875,
    "createdOn" : "5-09 08:02",
    "remarks" : "lucky"
  }
]

Comment: Perhaps add the structure of your `dict` object to the question?

Comment: I think you get array in result.data, and you try to load that to NSDictionary. so this will lead error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of your code is unnecessary. Mostly, you don't need to be casting to Objective-C types for arrays and dictionaries. So you need something like this:

```
KCNetWorkTool.tool.getRecordListWith(UserID: userID, Date: dateLabel.text!) { (result) in
    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
    if let envelopes = result.data["list"] as? [[String: Any?]] {
        self.recordModel.append(envelopes.forEach { EnvelopeModel(dictionary: $0) })
    }
    self.recordTable.reloadData()
}
```

Haven't checked that in a compiler, but something like that.

Comment: thanks bro ,  but  i still get an error     Value of optional type '[String : Any]?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'subscript' of wrapped base type '[Strin

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you need to understand the basic structure of json copy and past your json string to a json formatter online tool and,

check from root key to end key. Try to unwrap the value from result. debug properly.

On second chance you are converting direct Data to [String : Any]. What Api calling tool you are using Alamofire or other library.

you can use JsonDecoder class to convert Data to your model class which is nativ tool in iOS.

Make your json to a structs and with root struct you can parse Data to whole model structured data.

```
struct Root<T> : Codable
{
    var yourRootKey: T?
}

struct Price : Codable
{
    var yoursubKey: Double?
}

Pass in decoder like Root<Price>.self

do{
   let response = try JsonDecoder().decode(Root<Price>.self, for : result.data)
}catch let error{
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```